# zend framework project shows blank page without any errors

Tags: apache, zend-framework

i created a simple project with zf and it works fine, but when i copy it to other pc 
it just show a blank page without any page or errors ?

my zf version is 1.9 and in other pc zf version 1.9 too

what do you do about this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have error reporting enabled on your machine?
Make sure, that you have these lines in your php.ini file:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = on
```

It will help you to find the problem by showing the error.
If it doesn't help, try to put this code in your index.php in public directory

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Also make sure, that DocumentRoot points to your Zend project public folder.

Comment: in my config file (application.ini ) i have this line code
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

Comment: i see, but it doesn't guarantee anything.
try to put ini_set('display_errors', 1); in your index.php file rigth after the <?php tag.
If it doesn't help try to put this 
 die('test');

Comment: Unfortunately your answer didn't help me u.u Any other suggestions? <=)

Answer (score 0):

Are the memory limits the same on both servers?  I have seen similar results using php (with zend, albeit). When I run out of memory, just a blank white screen is the result.

Comment: How can I verify this is the cause of my problem? Can you give me another tip so I can try it? Thanks =)

Answer (score -1):

This error is caused because **your server is running version 4 of PHP, change to version 5** and it will work.